# Recognize if the windows is a popup to change CSS value

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, popup

I have the following code for my homepage:

```
<div class="unit one-fifth" style="width: 18.6%;  padding-top: 0px;">*content of my sidebar*</div>
<div class="unit four-fifths" style="width: 81.4%;  padding-top: 0px;"> content of my page*</div>
```

I'm currently using https://github.com/cobyism/gridism as my grid framework. 
The thing is that I have several buttons or texts that open a popup window to filter certain search criteria.

This, for example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open("Modulos.php?modname=misc/EscogerCurso.php","","scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=400"); return false;">Escoger</a>
```

The problem is that these popup windows open with the same Grid system, but they won't load the sidebar, only the main content:

```
<div class="unit four-fifths" style="width: 81.4%;  padding-top: 0px;"> content of the popup*</div>
```

The problem is evident: the popup loads leaving 20% of the page blank...
[image: the main Div is only 80%]

The main Div is only 80% of the page, the remaining 20% is for the sidebar.
What could I do?
I was thinking maybe some conditional that recognizes the popup and changes the class of the main Div, or changes the width from 80% to 100%, but I certainly don't know how.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You have conflicting quotes.

This is why you should not use inline event handling, instead abstract it so that the double quotes wrapping "window.open(...)" do not get escaped by the quotes inside window.open(" ... ").

If you insist on using inline events (please don't), escape them like \" or simply use single quotes ''

Comment: Thank you. I will correct this ;)

Comment: Do you have any advise on how could I solve the issue? ;/